# Vim syntax highlighting not working (but works in gvim?)

Tags: python, vim

I've followed all instructions given on this site with an empty .vim folder, but for some reason, python highlighting is not working on my system. It only highlights the comments and a few variables - nothing like the picture.

http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2009/07/vim-part-i-improved-python-syntax.html

Is there some other setting I am forgetting?

I'm also using ubuntu 10.04 if that matters.

A weird other note - it works in gvim, but not vim?

Comment: what terminal and is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colorscheme used in that tutorial is only for gvim.  Try changing your colorscheme.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the colorscheme, you should check out CSApprox.vim. It allows you to use colorschemes made for gvim in vim.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390

Answer (score 0):

I think ubuntu installs vim in a minimal package (vim-tiny) with some features missing. You can try to upgrade your vim to the full version:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-full
```

Comment: There's no package for vim-full.

Comment: Have a look at this official HowTo guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto I tried it by myself with ubuntu 8.04 and the package was installed with no problems.